# ANDROID: Convert OpenGL onDraw to bitmap then display bitmap in an ImageView

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

Good day sirs.

I'm having problem in displaying a bitmap that comes from an openGL in my own imageView.

First, I'm creating an openGL with 3D objects inside (Like cubes, sphere etc.)

Then, I convert the openGL onDraw view to a bitmap (i use this codes)

```
public static Bitmap createBitmapFromGLSurface(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl)
        throws OutOfMemoryError {
    int bitmapBuffer[] = new int[w * h];
    int bitmapSource[] = new int[w * h];
    IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapBuffer);
    intBuffer.position(0);

    try {
        gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);
        int offset1, offset2;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            offset1 = i * w;
            offset2 = (h - i - 1) * w;
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                int texturePixel = bitmapBuffer[offset1 + j];
                int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;
                bitmapSource[offset2 + j] = pixel;
            }
        }
    } catch (GLException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

Well, it captures the view of the onDraw and turn it to bitmap, but what I need is to make the openGL a background process, convert its view to a bitmap, the display the bitmap in an imageview in my main activity.

I removed the

```
setContentView(ourSurfaceView)
```

in my mainActivity but after removing it and changing with my layout.xml
the bitmap I'm creating from openGL is not functioning. (Sorry for my english)

THanks in advanced. :)

Answer (score 0):

With 4.2(API Level 17) EGL got introduced into the android sdk. EGL makes offscreen rendering possible.
Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13504396/1404216